# mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/xvdf1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error

Tags: mount

I am unable to mount more than one EBS volumes in an EC2 instance. I have 3 EBS Volumes which are 'root-volume' leftovers from previously terminated EC2 instances(Named: `/dev/xvdf1`, `/dev/xvdg1`, `/dev/xvde1`). I was successfully able to mount `/dev/xvde1` using the following command:

```
#mount /dev/xvde1 /home/ec2-user/xvde1
```

But when I repeat this procedure for xvdf1 and xvdg1 **I am getting this Error**:

```
ec2-user]# mount -t xfs /dev/xvdf1 /home/ec2-user/xvdf1

**mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/xvdf1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.**
```

Supporting Outputs:

1)

```
ec2-user]# lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0   8G  0 disk
└─xvda1 202:1    0   8G  0 part /
xvdf    202:80   0   8G  0 disk
└─xvdf1 202:81   0   8G  0 part
xvdg    202:96   0   8G  0 disk
└─xvdg1 202:97   0   8G  0 part 
xvde    202:64   0   8G  0 disk
└─xvde1 202:65   0   8G  0 part /home/ec2-user/xvde1*  **-->I was able to mount this one successfully.**
```

2. 

```
ec2-user]# blkid

/dev/xvda1: LABEL="/" UUID="f25f5092-0401-4edb-9fac-c57f3c673803" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="Linux" PARTUUID="893c59db-bd86-4d67-b40f-221bc82c14c8"
/dev/xvdf1: LABEL="/" UUID="f5bd1ae0-85b5-4686-85ff-ed8deb328c92" TYPE="xfs" PARTLABEL="Linux" PARTUUID="870dbb7e-9386-480b-a946-4d0f7ab5c405"
/dev/xvdg1: LABEL="/" UUID="f5bd1ae0-85b5-4686-85ff-ed8deb328c92" TYPE="xfs" PARTLABEL="Linux" PARTUUID="870dbb7e-9386-480b-a946-4d0f7ab5c405"
/dev/xvde1: LABEL="/" UUID="f5bd1ae0-85b5-4686-85ff-ed8deb328c92" TYPE="xfs" PARTLABEL="Linux" PARTUUID="870dbb7e-9386-480b-a946-4d0f7ab5c405"
```

3. 

```
ec2-user]# file -s /dev/xvdf1

*/dev/xvdf1: SGI XFS filesystem data (blksz 4096, inosz 512, v2 dirs)*

ec2-user]# file -s /dev/xvdg1

*/dev/xvdg1: SGI XFS filesystem data (blksz 4096, inosz 512, v2 dirs)*

 ec2-user]# file -s /dev/xvde1

*/dev/xvde1: SGI XFS filesystem data (blksz 4096, inosz 512, v2 dirs)*
```

4. 

```
ec2-user]# mkfs -t xfs /dev/xvdf1  //Tried formatting xvdf1

*mkfs.xfs: No such file or directory*
```

Answer (score 45):

If the instances were launched using the same AMI then their root volumes will have been created from the same EBS snapshot, so the problem is likely [duplicate XFS UUIDs](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=604879). The error message from `mount` isn't very helpful, but you may see errors like this in `/var/log/messages` or equivalent:

```
Jan 13 23:30:29 ip-172-31-15-234 kernel: XFS (nvme1n1): Filesystem has duplicate UUID 56282b3b-c1f3-425e-90db-e9e26def629d - can't mount
```

(This example is from a t3 instance using NVMe storage, but it's not NVMe-specific.)

Every XFS filesystem has a (supposedly) unique ID stored on-disk, which protects you from accidentally mounting the same filesystem multiple times. Because the EBS snapshot/restore process is a block-level copy, any volumes you create from a snapshot will have the same UUID as the source volume so you can only mount one at a time.

You can view the UUID for a volume by attaching it but not mounting it, then running [xfs_db](https://www.linux.org/docs/man8/xfs_db.html) to examine the attached disk:

```
# xfs_db -c uuid /dev/nvme1n1
UUID = 56282b3b-c1f3-425e-90db-e9e26def629d
```

(EDIT: The [blkid](https://www.linux.org/docs/man8/blkid.html) command will also show you the UUID, even if the device is mounted.)

To work around the issue, you can either use the XFS-specific `nouuid` [mount option](https://www.linux.org/docs/man5/xfs.html) to temporarily ignore the duplicate check, e.g.

```
# mount -t xfs -o nouuid /dev/nvme1n1 /mnt
```

or you can use [xfs_admin](https://www.linux.org/docs/man8/xfs_admin.html) to permanently change the UUID on the volume:

```
# xfs_admin -U generate /dev/nvme1n1
Clearing log and setting UUID
writing all SBs
new UUID = 1eb81512-3f22-4b79-9a35-f22f29745c60
```

Comment: sudo mount -t xfs -o nouuid  /dev/xvdc1 /u02 worked beautifully

Comment: Duplicate UUIDs! That'd taken me awhile on my own. Thank you!

Comment: mount -t xfs -o nouuid /dev/xvdf3 /mnt/data/ its works awesome .

Answer (score 2):

Used the -f (Force) option with mkfs to reformat the partition,

`mkfs -t xfs -f /dev/xvdg1*`

Re-executed the command

`mount /dev/xvdg1 /home/ec2-user/xvdg1/`

Output:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        483M   84K  483M   1% /dev
tmpfs           493M     0  493M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvda1      7.8G  1.1G  6.6G  14% /
/dev/xvde1      8.0G  1.3G  6.8G  16% /home/ec2-user/xvde1
/dev/xvdf1      8.0G   33M  8.0G   1% /home/ec2-user/xvdf1
/dev/xvdg1      8.0G   33M  8.0G   1% /home/ec2-user/xvdg1
```

Comment: ```-f``` is not an option of ```mkfs``` for me...?

Comment: Wouldn't this delete the contents of the disk? :S

Comment: This will clean the drive... Please check before running it...

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me, amazon linux image 2.

```
mount -t xfs -o nouuid /dev/xvdb /data

xfs_admin -U generate /dev/xvdb
```

It helped to regenerating UUID and mounting through fstab.

Answer (score 1):

Basically this error occurs when you try to attach one instance root volume to another instance, so for that proper formatting of that volume is necessary so we could use
mkfs -v -t ext4 /dev/xvdf
this command will format root volume & ready to mount
mount /dev/xvdf /desired directory

we can mount root volume to another ec2 instance but we have to format it & data gets erase so create new volume attach that to old root volume, copy data from root volume to created volume & then we can attach new volume to another ec2 instance (via snapshot also)

Answer (score 0):

> mount: /mnt/tidb: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on
> /dev/nvme0n2, missing codepage or helper program, or other error

.

please

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/nvme0n2
mount /dev/nvme0n2  /mnt/tidb
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks, this helped to mount the faulty OS disk as an additional disk on other Linux box for further troubleshoot and correction for AWS Amazon Linux v2.

mount -t xfs -o nouuid /dev/nvme1n1p1 /old_os

xfs_admin -U generate /dev/nvme2n1p1 (It helped to regenerating UUID and mounting through fstab)