# AWS: Can't mount my restored volume (EBS snapshot)

Tags: linux, mount, amazon-ebs, nvme, block-device

I restored an EBS volume from AWS Backup and attached it to a new EC2 instance. When I `lsblk` I can see it under the name `/dev/nvme1n1`.

More specifically the output of `lsblk` is:

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0         7:0    0   25M  1 loop /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/4046
loop1         7:1    0 55.4M  1 loop /snap/core18/2128
loop2         7:2    0 61.9M  1 loop /snap/core20/1169
loop3         7:3    0 67.3M  1 loop /snap/lxd/21545
loop4         7:4    0 32.5M  1 loop /snap/snapd/13640
loop5         7:5    0 55.5M  1 loop /snap/core18/2246
loop6         7:6    0 67.2M  1 loop /snap/lxd/21835
nvme0n1     259:0    0    8G  0 disk 
└─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0    8G  0 part /
nvme1n1     259:2    0  100G  0 disk
```

```
# parted -l /dev/nvme1n1 print
Model: Amazon Elastic Block Store (nvme)
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 8590MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  8590MB  8589MB  primary  ext4         boot


Error: /dev/nvme1n1: unrecognised disk label
Model: Amazon Elastic Block Store (nvme)                                  
Disk /dev/nvme1n1: 107GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags:
```

As you can see `nvme1n1` has no partitions, although AWS states that

> Volumes that were created from snapshots likely have a file system on them already;

As a result, when I try to mount it on a folder with:

```
sudo mkdir mount_point
sudo mount /dev/nvme1n1 mount_point/
```

I get

`mount: /home/ubuntu/mount_point: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/nvme1n1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.`

The volume has data inside:

```
/dev/nvme1n1: data
```

Using `sudo mkfs -t xfs /dev/nvme1n1` to create a filesystem is not an option as Amazon states that:

> **Warning**
> Do not use this command if you're mounting a volume that already has data on it (for example, a volume that was created from a snapshot). Otherwise, you'll format the volume and delete the existing data.

Indeed I tried it with a second dummy ebs snapshot that I recovered and all I got is a dummy `lost+found` [linux folder](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18154/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-lostfound-folder-in-linux-and-unix).

This EBS recovered snapshot has useful data inside, how can I mount it without destroying them?

If that helps:

```
sudo dmesg|tail && tail -40 /var/log/syslog
[259510.079807] squashfs: Unknown parameter 'nouuid'
[259510.081864] fuseblk: Unknown parameter 'nouuid'
[259530.034094] squashfs: Unknown parameter 'nouuid'
[259530.036337] fuseblk: Unknown parameter 'nouuid'
[259588.954190] squashfs: Unknown parameter 'nouuid'
[259588.956302] fuseblk: Unknown parameter 'nouuid'
[259618.283956] squashfs: Unknown parameter 'nouuid'
[259618.286027] fuseblk: Unknown parameter 'nouuid'
[259790.237677] squashfs: Unknown parameter 'nouuid'
[259790.239915] fuseblk: Unknown parameter 'nouuid'
Nov  8 12:11:22 ip-10-71-0-16 dbus-daemon[467]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.PackageKit'
Nov  8 12:11:22 ip-10-71-0-16 systemd[1]: Started PackageKit Daemon.
Nov  8 12:16:28 ip-10-71-0-16 PackageKit: daemon quit
Nov  8 12:16:28 ip-10-71-0-16 systemd[1]: packagekit.service: Succeeded.
Nov  8 12:17:01 ip-10-71-0-16 CRON[25118]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Nov  8 12:18:07 ip-10-71-0-16 multipath: nvme1n1: failed to get udev uid: Invalid argument
Nov  8 12:18:07 ip-10-71-0-16 multipath: nvme1n1: uid = nvme.1d0f-766f6c3066643562613336373562646331303430-416d617a6f6e20456c617374696320426c6f636b2053746f7265-00000001 (sysfs)
Nov  8 12:18:21 ip-10-71-0-16 kernel: [259240.333109] EXT4-fs (nvme1n1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null). Quota mode: none.
Nov  8 12:21:22 ip-10-71-0-16 kernel: [259420.897564] pci 0000:00:1f.0: [1d0f:8061] type 00 class 0x010802
Nov  8 12:21:22 ip-10-71-0-16 kernel: [259420.897692] pci 0000:00:1f.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0x00000000-0x00003fff]
Nov  8 12:21:22 ip-10-71-0-16 kernel: [259420.898762] pci 0000:00:1f.0: BAR 0: assigned [mem 0x80000000-0x80003fff]
Nov  8 12:21:22 ip-10-71-0-16 kernel: [259420.898899] nvme nvme2: pci function 0000:00:1f.0
Nov  8 12:21:22 ip-10-71-0-16 kernel: [259420.898931] nvme 0000:00:1f.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
Nov  8 12:21:22 ip-10-71-0-16 kernel: [259420.911982] nvme nvme2: 2/0/0 default/read/poll queues
Nov  8 12:21:22 ip-10-71-0-16 multipath: nvme2n1: failed to get udev uid: Invalid argument
Nov  8 12:21:22 ip-10-71-0-16 multipath: nvme2n1: uid = nvme.1d0f-766f6c3063336165616261376163396164323232-416d617a6f6e20456c617374696320426c6f636b2053746f7265-00000001 (sysfs)
Nov  8 12:21:25 ip-10-71-0-16 kernel: [259424.348064] EXT4-fs error (device nvme1n1): __ext4_find_entry:1524: inode #2: comm lsblk: reading directory lblock 0
Nov  8 12:21:57 ip-10-71-0-16 kernel: [259456.068352] Aborting journal on device nvme1n1-8.
Nov  8 12:21:57 ip-10-71-0-16 kernel: [259456.070935] Buffer I/O error on dev nvme1n1, logical block 13139968, lost sync page write
Nov  8 12:21:57 ip-10-71-0-16 kernel: [259456.080345] JBD2: Error -5 detected when updating journal superblock for nvme1n1-8.
Nov  8 12:22:15 ip-10-71-0-16 kernel: [259474.291166] EXT4-fs warning (device nvme1n1): htree_dirblock_to_tree:993: inode #2: lblock 0: comm rm: error -5 reading directory block
Nov  8 12:22:15 ip-10-71-0-16 kernel: [259474.291181] EXT4-fs warning (device nvme1n1): htree_dirblock_to_tree:993: inode #2: lblock 0: comm rm: error -5 reading directory block
Nov  8 12:22:19 ip-10-71-0-16 kernel: [259478.174816] EXT4-fs warning (device nvme1n1): htree_dirblock_to_tree:993: inode #2: lblock 0: comm ls: error -5 reading directory block
Nov  8 12:22:22 ip-10-71-0-16 kernel: [259481.580825] EXT4-fs warning (device nvme1n1): htree_dirblock_to_tree:993: inode #2: lblock 0: comm ls: error -5 reading directory block
Nov  8 12:22:49 ip-10-71-0-16 kernel: [259508.057079] squashfs: Unknown parameter 'nouuid'
Nov  8 12:22:49 ip-10-71-0-16 kernel: [259508.059713] fuseblk: Unknown parameter 'nouuid'
Nov  8 12:22:51 ip-10-71-0-16 kernel: [259510.079807] squashfs: Unknown parameter 'nouuid'
Nov  8 12:22:51 ip-10-71-0-16 kernel: [259510.081864] fuseblk: Unknown parameter 'nouuid'
Nov  8 12:23:11 ip-10-71-0-16 kernel: [259530.034094] squashfs: Unknown parameter 'nouuid'
Nov  8 12:23:11 ip-10-71-0-16 kernel: [259530.036337] fuseblk: Unknown parameter 'nouuid'
Nov  8 12:24:10 ip-10-71-0-16 kernel: [259588.954190] squashfs: Unknown parameter 'nouuid'
Nov  8 12:24:10 ip-10-71-0-16 kernel: [259588.956302] fuseblk: Unknown parameter 'nouuid'
Nov  8 12:24:39 ip-10-71-0-16 kernel: [259618.283956] squashfs: Unknown parameter 'nouuid'
Nov  8 12:24:39 ip-10-71-0-16 kernel: [259618.286027] fuseblk: Unknown parameter 'nouuid'
Nov  8 12:25:25 ip-10-71-0-16 multipath: nvme2n1: failed to get udev uid: Invalid argument
Nov  8 12:25:25 ip-10-71-0-16 multipath: nvme2n1: uid = nvme.1d0f-766f6c3063336165616261376163396164323232-416d617a6f6e20456c617374696320426c6f636b2053746f7265-00000001 (sysfs)
Nov  8 12:26:01 ip-10-71-0-16 multipath: nvme2n1: failed to get udev uid: Invalid argument
Nov  8 12:26:01 ip-10-71-0-16 multipath: nvme2n1: uid = nvme.1d0f-766f6c3063336165616261376163396164323232-416d617a6f6e20456c617374696320426c6f636b2053746f7265-00000001 (sysfs)
Nov  8 12:27:31 ip-10-71-0-16 kernel: [259790.237677] squashfs: Unknown parameter 'nouuid'
Nov  8 12:27:31 ip-10-71-0-16 kernel: [259790.239915] fuseblk: Unknown parameter 'nouuid'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/948408/mount-wrong-fs-type-bad-option-bad-superblock-on-dev-xvdf1-missing-codepage